# Fetching an image from express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to fetch an image from my express API. I use multer to store the images on my server. The images are in a folder called uploads. If I enter the whole path to the image on the server to insomnia/postman, I get the image returned.

The request looks like this (returns from MongoDB):

```
[
  {
    "_id": "60c6207219cf2bbf04c79a84",
    "nimi": "Selkätreeni",
    "treeninkesto": "60-75min",
    "image": "uploads/selkaToinen.jpg",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "60c620b019cf2bbf04c79a85",
    "nimi": "Rintatreeni",
    "treeninkesto": "60-75min",
    "image": "uploads/rintaToinen.jpg",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "60c620bb19cf2bbf04c79a86",
    "nimi": "Jalkatreeni",
    "treeninkesto": "60-75min",
    "image": "uploads/jalatToinen.jpg",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "60c620c219cf2bbf04c79a87",
    "nimi": "Käsitreeni",
    "treeninkesto": "60-75min",
    "image": "uploads/kadetToinen.jpg",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

```
const Cards = () => {
    const [cardData, setCardData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('');

   

    async function _getCardData() {
        try {

            await axios.get('MY-IP-ADDERSS:3000/api/cards/etusivucards')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);                
                setCardData(response.data);
                /* response.data.map(function(item, index) {
                    console.log(item.image)
                }) */
                
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setLoading(false);
            })
        } catch(err) {
            console.error(error);
        }

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        _getCardData();
    }, []);


return (
                <ScrollView style={{marginTop: 25}}>
            {
                cardData.map((item, index) => {
                    const img = item.image;

                    return(
                        <TouchableOpacity key={index}>
                        <Tile
                        imageSrc={ `MY-IP-ADDRESS:3000/api/${img}}`}
                        title={<Text title style={{color: '#FFF', fontFamily: 'MontserratBold'}}>{item.nimi}</Text>} featured
                        caption=
                        {<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                        <Text medium style={{color: '#FFF', fontFamily: 'MontserratSemiBold'}} >{item.treeninkesto}
                        </Text>
                        </View>
                        }
                        containerStyle={{ marginBottom: 5, marginLeft: 8.5}}  
                        height={150}  
                        width={'98%'}   
                        imageContainerStyle={{opacity: 0.9, borderRadius: 10}}
                                                
                        />
                       
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    );
                })
            }
            </ScrollView>
            )
```

I'm able to render everything else from the response, though I'm not able to render the image on a card element in the frontend with {item.image} in an inline map function iterating through a state array in which I stored the response.data. What am I doing wrong? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you please show your code where you attempt to render your image as well as the specific error message you receive?

Comment: Added the frontend code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
imageSrc={ `MY-IP-ADDRESS:3000/api/${img}}`}
```

It looks like the last backtick is in the wrong place in this line, or you put an extra brace before the last backtick.